# dvar float+ variable contains negative solution

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I am solving a linear programming problem with IBM ILOG CPLEX optimization studio. One of my decision variables is of the type float+. I define it as

dvar float+ A[P][G];

CPLEX produces the solution for this variable as a matrix where one of the elements is negative (equals -4e-10).

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: This "negative" component of is in essence `0` (depending on the magnitude of what you consider to be negligible w.r.t. other non-negative variable values).

Comment: @dfri Thank you for your answer!